# differentiate between a pin click and a map click?

Tags: maui

Is there a way to determine if the user has clicked a pin on the map? The Map.Clicked event only seems to fire if you click around the pin.

Comment: FYI: Google `maui map pin click` finds the Maui Map doc. Its "Interact with a pin" section shows what to do. As seen in Jason's answer. Please be sure to research carefully when you don't know how to do something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pin` has a [MarkerClicked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0#interact-with-a-pin) event

```
boardwalkPin.MarkerClicked += async (s, args) =>
{
    args.HideInfoWindow = true;
    string pinName = ((Pin)s).Label;
    await DisplayAlert("Pin Clicked", $"{pinName} was clicked.", "Ok");
};
```